# Rscript in terminal yields in "Error: RStudio not running"

Tags: r, command-line-interface, rstudio

I've been using for while Rstudio with R pre-installed, as usual. Some days ago I decided to run absolutely everything I can in the terminal/CLI, since some GUI/IDEs keep crashing over and over and doing my stuff in vim seem to me to be enough. I googled and tried to run a R script that I used to run with Rstudio, now using Rscript. I also added R and Rscript to PATH, ran `chmod +x` to the file, added the shebang to the R file, and yet the message that I get is this:

```
Error: RStudio not running
Execution halted
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why does it seem Rstudio is trying to run this script if I haven't even tried to use it in the command line? I have erased almost all the code and left only one line, that calls another R script, which clears the environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

# Clears everything
source("cleanAll.R")
```

cleanAll.R code:

```
rm(list = ls())     # Clears global environment
cat("\014")         # Clears the console
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
graphics.off()
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to run a function in your rscript that has to be called inside RStudio. What does this script do?

Comment: Not precisely a function, but actually another file in the same directory. Is it this what is calling Rstudio? It is not possible to use the source command without running Rstudio? I added the script code to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use the {rstudioapi} package.

You can't use this package unless you are in an interactive RStudio session. Hence the error `Error: RStudio not running`.

Are you trying to get the working directory? You should use `getwd()`
if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Remove setwd() command in .R file and run, It is working perfectly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23018471)

Comment: Hi @EneaDume I clarified author answer, Because in his code there is a command used called setwd(), If he remove that command, Code is working fine without 'Error: RStudio not running' this error. Thanks